# Live view of online visitors

Tags: lamp, live, visitors

I'm looking for a tool/script/method to see live who's visiting my web site at any given time. My site uses the LAMP stack.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [one tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/who-is-online-widget-php-mysql-jquery/), and [another](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/The-Quickest-Way-To-Count-Users-Online-With-PHP/1/), and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051895/whats-the-easiest-way-to-determine-is-a-user-in-online-php-mysql). [Google also turns up a bunch of them](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20mysql%20users%20online#hl=en&q=php+mysql+display+users+online&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=php+mysql+display+users+online&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=f36d3c22a357aa92).

Answer (score 1):

Try [HitsLink](http://www.hitslink.com/) -- they present data near real-time.

Answer (score 1):

We've had great success with [LiveZilla](http://www.livezilla.net/) and [ClickAndChat](http://www.clickandchat.com/). LiveZilla is free, but you need to host it yousrelf. ClickAndChat is not free, but comes with hosting.

They're both actually primarily "chat" based software for interacting with your visitors, but you can easilly throw that side out and just use it for instant tracking of visitors.