# Live Website Monitoring Tool

Tags: traffic, tracking, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Live view of online visitors](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/live-view-of-online-visitors)

What is a good tool to monitor a website's traffic live? Is there something that shows a feed of people who is currently on your website?

Answer (score 0):

I have heard good things about http://chartbeat.com/

Also, most online chat tools show you how is currently on your website e. g. Olark